# How can I fix this attribute error with my novice webscraping code?

Tags: python, web-scraping, error-handling, attributes

I am trying to learn to webscrape by scraping heights and weights of NFL players by particular positions.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Base URL for the NFL player stats page
base_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/'

# List to store player data
player_data = []

# Loop through the years 2014 to 2021
for year in range(2014, 2022):
  # Send a GET request to the URL
  response = requests.get(f'{base_url}{year}/')

  # Parse the HTML of the page
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

  # Find all rows in the player stats table
  rows = soup.find('table', {'id': 'players'}).tbody.find_all('tr')[1:]
    
 

  # Loop through each row
for row in rows:
    # Find the player name cell
    name_cell = row.find('th')

    # Check if the cell is valid (some rows may not have player data)
if name_cell:
          # Extract the player name and link
    try:
            name = name_cell.a.text
    except AttributeError:
            name = ''
   #35 
    try:
            position = row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'position'}).text
    except AttributeError:
            position = ''
            
    try:
            link = name_cell.a['href']
    except AttributeError:
            link = ''
        
      # Extract the player height and weight
    try:
            height = row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'height'}).text
    except AttributeError:
            height = ''
            
    try:    
                weight = row.find('td', {'data-stat': 'weight'}).text
    except AttributeError:
                weight = ''
        
      # Add the player data to the list
player_data.append({
        'name': name,
        'position': position,
        'link': link,
        'height': height,
        'weight': weight
      })

# Print the player data
print(player_data)
c.execute(player_data)
getAll('player_data',c)
querySave(player_data, c, 'NFLHeightWeight')

print("Done!")
```

I get the error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'

I have seen this error in other questions asked, but the solutions did not really work.

How can I fix this for my particular case? I tried to make sure what I am searching for is not blank.

Thank you!

Comment: You have to check that `soup.find()` successfully found the table before trying to access its `tbody`.

Comment: Good first question, keep posting!

Answer (score 1):

Check that you found the table before trying to find its `tbody`.

```
for year in range(2014, 2022):
    # Send a GET request to the URL
    response = requests.get(f'{base_url}{year}/')

    # Parse the HTML of the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'players'})
    if table:
        rows = table.tbody.find_all('tr')[1:]
    else:
        print(f"No players table found for year {year}")
        continue

    # rest of loop here
```

Also, the `for row in rows:` loop needs to be indented so it's inside the `for year in range(2014, 2022):` loop. Otherwise it will just use the `rows` from the last year in the loop.